# Why the shape of cursor is wrong during my drag-drop operation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some code to do drag-drop between items of two list boxes. which I got it to work finally. so it is doing the drag-drop But the shape of the cursor icon is Wrong. for example when I am doing the "drop" on the second list box the icon is still that Stop Circle or whatever its name is. not sure. but yea the icon of the cursor is wrong. Any thoughts how can I fix this?

Comment: why don't you just change cursor manually if that disturbs you: this.Cursor=Cursors.XXXXX;

Comment: I want to know what is the root cause of this behavior and fix it there.

Comment: Did you add the "DragOver" event handler to your Drag&Drop target control? In the event you are suppose to set the "eventargs.Effect" to the type of Drag&Drop-drop mode will be used.

Comment: Post code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @MarvinSmit : Thanks, please post this as answer. I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks Hans, the DragOver trick that Marvin mentioned is fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

In the DragEnter event of the ListBox you can set the DragEventArgs.Effect to a DragDropEffects value:

```
private void ListBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}
```

Comment: does not work! :( I also wrote a Debug.Writeline in that method to make sure it is getting in it and yes it is going in there but the shape is still the same Blocked circle.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what control you are using, but aside from setting the correct DragDropEffect, if you are using the RichTextBox and have EnableAutoDragDrop = true, I noticed some issues where it wants to do a `Move` from some sources that don't allow it. Holding down [ctrl] switches the dragdrop mode to `Copy` and allows you to drop it in the target control.